# Troubleshooting Email Bounce Issues

Tags: email

We are sending couple of emails to our customer from Cases and for the past few weeks we are getting back lot of undeliverable email even though the email address is valid. I'm troubleshooting the issue and help me to clarify my doubts

1. From some emails I can see send address is postmaster@ and for others it is mailer-daemon@salesforce.com. Is this signifies anything ?
2. If the sender is mailer-daemon@salesforce.com then is it due to SFDC mailer daemon ?
3. "5.4.7 [internal] exceeded max time without delivery" error message signifies any particular issue ?

Answer (score 1):

- All issues happened only because, either the email address used is a `bad email address` (it is doesn't exist or format is incorrect). Yahoo, gmail, hotmail etc. bounce these email immediately and return a mail with error code, in your case it seems `5.4.7`.
- *mailer-daemon@salesforce.com* is the internal sender which sends email from organization's user's behalf.
- *postmaster@* email addresses are from domain from where this email bounces. And provide detailed error.

Comment: Sample                                                      "A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

>>> <customer email address> (Undelivered): 554 5.4.7 [internal] exceeded max time without delivery"

Comment: @T3chn1nja This happens because of bad email address or email address doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Thanks responsive.. just one more thing is it possible to identify the mail route ex: parameters like Return-Path, Return-Path etc

Comment: I couldn't understand "Return-path" meaning here. Can you provide more details? @T3chn1nja

Comment: @T3chn1nja In **Email Administration | Deliverability > Bounce Administration** This may help you.

Comment: Please check the trust status of your Instance Also it is recommended to route your emails though company domain also check this https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_send_through_salesforce_setup.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

- We can email the customer from our personal email address.
- The customer disabled the firewall on his side, no dice.
- Nobody within the customer's org is reporting any issue with emails sending/receiving hosted on the same domain.

This is the error being returned by mailer-daemon@salesforce (I've removed our customer's email address):

> > > redacted-email@redacted-domain.com (Undelivered): 554 5.4.7 [internal] exceeded max time without delivery

For us it turned out to be that the customer didn't have PTR record for their domain.

Comment: Hi @DataBonanza - please do not post 'I am having this problem too' as an answer - see the [help], [ask] and [answer]. you are better off posting a new question with a link to this question if it provides context.

Comment: Sorry about that, I corrected my post w/ the solution I found to work.